# How to typecheck generic parameters in the constructor?

Tags: java, oop, dart

In many OOP languages, such as Dart or Java, you can parameterize arguments that get passed into an object's constructor. What's the best way to handle unexpected parameter types in the constructor? For example, in this Dart code snippet, the plus operator (`+`) is used, and let's say that only makes sense in the context of ints or strings:

```
class Wrap <T> {
  OK;

  factory Wrap (T a) {
    if (a is String) print ("Type is String");
    else if (a is int) print ("Type is int");

    return Wrap ._ (a);
  }

  Wrap ._ (this.a);
}

main () {
  / *
    var obj = Wrap <Map <int, String >> (<int, String> {0: '1'});
    var obj = Wrap <String> ('2');
    var obj = Wrap <int> (2);
  * /
  print (obj.a + obj.a);
}
```

I'm interested in the OOP way to handle this (specifically in Dart and Java if possible).

Some ideas I've considered are:

- Returning null in the constructor. However, it looks like some languages, like Java, [don't allow this][1]
- Have some convenient way to gracefully create the object, even though the type is unexpected

Comment: Are you asking "should a factory method return null if you pass the wrong argument types?"  If so, I would say throwing an exception would be the most logical response, but whatever you do you should document it if it is part of a public API, and then there is no confusion.

Comment: In a [strongly-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language like Java, you cannot pass the wrong type to the constructor — the compiler would never have compiled such code. That is the benefit of a strongly-typed language, to prevent such errors happening at runtime. Constructors (and other methods) declare the type of each argument they are willing to receive, and the compiler enforces that contract.

Comment: Dart factory constructors used to allow returning `null`. With the null safety update, that's no longer allowed - a factory must provide an instance of the type it's a constructor for. I think you're confusing factory methods and constructors. Constructors are tasked with constructing an object of the class' type. Factories are tasked with creating whatever they're factories for. They're not strongly bound to a specific class or type.

Comment: If the generic type parameter should only take certain type arguments, then the type parameter should have an upper bound. For example, in typescript `class Foo<T extends string | number> { ... }` guarantees you cannot instantiate the class with `T` as something totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlie-armstrong commented, currently the best and safest way to deal with unexpected types in the type parameter of a generic class is to throw an exception.

Although this does not prevent the creation of the instance, the exception is enough because it notifies the programmer that something is wrong, giving him only one option, to handle the error / exception, otherwise the program is terminated.

Below is an example of what was said above:

```
class Wrap<T> {
  T a;

  factory Wrap(T a) {
    if (!(T == String || T == int))
      throw(Error_Wrap("Invalid type ${T}"));
    return Wrap._(a);
  }

  Wrap._(this.a);
}

class Error_Wrap extends Error {
  String error;
  Error_Wrap(this.error);

  @override
  String toString() => error;
}

main () {
  var obj;
  try {
    obj = Wrap<Map<int, String>>(<int, String>{ 0 : '2'});
  } on Error_Wrap catch(e, s) {
    print("${e}\n${s}");
    return;
  }

  print(obj.a + obj.a);
}
```

Thanks @AnilRedshift for editing and reopening the question.